# How to concat or Listagg two values in a same column to join it with the values in other column

Tags: join, select, left-join, oracle12c, listagg

I have two tables :

TABLE_A

```
pos_id    res_id     bb_id    bsk_name
1122      10000       1444     type_1 
1122      10000       5678     type_2
1122      10001       1444     type_1
1122      10001       5678     type_2
1122      10002       1467     type_1
1122      10002       5678     type_2
1122      10003       1467     type_1
1122      10003       5678     type_2
```

table_b

```
pos_id    row_id    bb_id     bsk_name
1122        1        1444      type_1
1122        1        5678      type_2
1122        2        1467      type_1
1122        2        5678      type_2
```

I wanted to join the table_a and table_b to get the row_id for each res_id.

the res_id 10000 and 10001 has to have the row_id 1 and res_id 10002 and 10003 has to have the row_id 2.  but since there is no unique column to join these two tables i get duplicated values for the bb_id 5678 since they are the same in both row_id's.

So Is there a way like to listagg the bb_id's with the erg_id in table_a and row_id in table_b to join these two tables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CAST(COLLECT(...) AS ...)` to aggregate the rows into a user-defined collection and then compare the collections.

First, create a nested-table-type collection:

```sql
CREATE TYPE int_list AS TABLE OF INT;
```

Then you can use:

```sql
SELECT a.pos_id,
       a.res_id,
       a.bb_id,
       a.bsk_name,
       b.row_id,
       b.bsk_name
FROM   (
  SELECT a.*,
         CAST(
           COLLECT(bb_id) OVER (PARTITION BY pos_id, res_id)
           AS int_list
         ) AS all_bb_ids
  FROM   table_a a
) a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT b.*,
         CAST(
           COLLECT(bb_id) OVER (PARTITION BY pos_id, row_id)
           AS int_list
         ) AS all_bb_ids
  FROM   table_b b
) b
ON (    a.pos_id = b.pos_id
    AND a.all_bb_ids = b.all_bb_ids
    AND a.bb_id = b.bb_id)
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TABLE_A ( pos_id, res_id, bb_id, bsk_name ) AS
SELECT 1122, 10000, 1444, 'type_1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1122, 10000, 5678, 'type_2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1122, 10001, 1444, 'type_1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1122, 10001, 5678, 'type_2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1122, 10002, 1467, 'type_1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1122, 10002, 5678, 'type_2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1122, 10003, 1467, 'type_1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1122, 10003, 5678, 'type_2' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table_b (pos_id, row_id, bb_id, bsk_name) AS
SELECT 1122, 1, 1444, 'type_1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1122, 1, 5678, 'type_2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1122, 2, 1467, 'type_1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1122, 2, 5678, 'type_2' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | POS_ID | RES_ID | BB_ID | BSK_NAME | ROW_ID | BSK_NAME |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1122 | 10000 | 1444 | type_1 | 1 | type_1 |
> | 1122 | 10000 | 5678 | type_2 | 1 | type_2 |
> | 1122 | 10001 | 1444 | type_1 | 1 | type_1 |
> | 1122 | 10001 | 5678 | type_2 | 1 | type_2 |
> | 1122 | 10002 | 1467 | type_1 | 2 | type_1 |
> | 1122 | 10002 | 5678 | type_2 | 2 | type_2 |
> | 1122 | 10003 | 1467 | type_1 | 2 | type_1 |
> | 1122 | 10003 | 5678 | type_2 | 2 | type_2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7341e584efaccd2b5e23fdbeb79adbdf)*

---

#### Update

You could also use `LISTAGG` to aggregate the data; however, if the aggregated string will exceed 4000 bytes then the aggregation will fail (using `CAST(COLLECT(...) ...)` does not have this limitation but does require you create a collection data type):

```sql
SELECT a.pos_id,
       a.res_id,
       a.bb_id,
       a.bsk_name,
       b.row_id,
       b.bsk_name
FROM   (
  SELECT a.*,
         LISTAGG(bb_id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY bb_id)
           OVER (PARTITION BY pos_id, res_id) AS all_bb_ids
  FROM   table_a a
) a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT b.*,
         LISTAGG(bb_id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY bb_id)
           OVER (PARTITION BY pos_id, row_id) AS all_bb_ids
  FROM   table_b b
) b
ON (    a.pos_id = b.pos_id
    AND a.all_bb_ids = b.all_bb_ids
    AND a.bb_id = b.bb_id)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4c6421e1418e27a7226114d29a31c4ed)*